# How can I connect to a service from another container?

Tags: docker

Hi I have 2 separate projects with `docker-compose` - `A` and `B`.
Project `B` has it's own Redis and I want to connect to this `B`'s Redis from `A` project.
How do I do this?

Comment: May [this post](https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/swarm/deploy-multi-service-app/) helps you?

Comment: So, there are 2 docker-compose.yaml here?

Comment: @atline yes - I have 2 docker-compose files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pre-existing network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network):

> If you want your containers to join a pre-existing network, use the external option

**Sample folder structure:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/cc$ ls
prj1  prj2
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/cc$ tree
.
├── prj1
│   └── docker-compose.yaml
└── prj2
    └── docker-compose.yaml

2 directories, 2 files
```

**prj1/docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  service_1:
    image: alpine
    tty: true
```

**prj2/docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  service_2:
    image: alpine
    tty: true

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: prj1_default
```

**Check if container could visit each other:**

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/cc/prj2$ docker exec -it prj2_service_2_1 ping service_1
PING service_1 (192.168.192.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.192.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.192.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.148 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.192.2: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.161 ms
```

You can see with 1st docker-compose.yaml, it will generate a network for this compose, here it's `prj1_default`, it depends on the folder name (prj1) which locate the first docker-compose.yaml.

Then, in 2rd docker-compose.yaml, just use the first network as the default network. With this way, the containers which generated by two different docker-compose.yaml could be in the same network, so they can visit each other. Then, for your case, prjB is able to visit prjA's redis.